# What's the difference between "numpy.add(a,b)" and "a+b"?

Tags: numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

Is there any difference between `numpy.add(a,b)` and `a+b` when adding two ndarrays a and b?
The documentation says that `numpy.add` is the ["Equivalent to x1 + x2 in terms of array broadcasting."](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html).
But I don't unserstand what this means, since `numpy.add(numpy.array([1,2,3]),4)` also works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python syntax, `a+b` is translated to `a.__add__(b)`.  `a.__add__` is a method that implements addition for objects of type `a`.  A number has such a method, a list does as well (`[1,3]+[4]`) and so does a string (`'abc'+'d'`).

`numpy` has implemented `__add__` (and other standard `__...` methods) for its `ndarray` class (at least for the numeric `dtypes`).

That's all standard Python and `numpy` and been around for ever.

`np.add` is a `ufunc`. Look at its doc - see the `out` parameter, and the `Binary ufuncs:` section.  It's a function, and has some methods like `reduce`, `reduceat`, etc that `a.__add__` (and `+`) does not.

If you have two arrays or numbers and you want to sum them, the natural thing is to use `+`, `a+b`.  `np.add` is useful in some special cases

Compare, for example, what happens to two lists:

```
In [16]: [1,2,3]+[4]
Out[16]: [1, 2, 3, 4]     # default list concatenation
In [17]: np.add([1,2,3],[4])
Out[17]: array([5, 6, 7])   # convert lists to arrays and sum
```

or an example using 2d broadcasting:

```
In [19]: np.add([[1],[2],[3]],[4,1])
Out[19]: 
array([[5, 2],
       [6, 3],
       [7, 4]])
In [20]: np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]+np.array([4,1])
Out[20]: 
array([[5, 2],
       [6, 3],
       [7, 4]])
```

And your example:

```
In [21]: numpy.add(numpy.array([1,2,3]),4)
Out[21]: array([5, 6, 7])
In [22]: numpy.array([1,2,3])+4
Out[22]: array([5, 6, 7])
```

"Equivalent to x1 + x2 in terms of array broadcasting." means, they both work and do the same thing.

`broadcasting` is another subject.

==================

The `@` operator and `np.matmul` parallel isn't quite the same.  The `@` operator is a recent addition to the Python interpreter.  It is translated to a call to the `__matmul__` method - if defined.  New `numpy` versions have such a definition.  But the method is not defined for Python numbers or lists.  There is also a function version, `np.matmul`, referencing the same code.  There is also a `x.dot` and `np.dot` pairing, but no Python recognized operator or `x.__dot__`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
If I got this right, numpy.add is faster (if it can be assured that a and b are ndarrays) than a+b since it is a ufunc?

Comment: The fact that one is a ufunc and the other a method shouldn't make a difference in speed.  That's a user interface issue, not a speed one.  I use `+` unless I need the added functionality of `add` (such as in `add.reduceat`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `add()` was first, the the library improved and gained normal mathematical operators.

BTW, we witness the same thing now with Python 3.5 and numpy, where matrix multiplication can be performed by the operator `@`. Prior to that, matrix mult of arrays could be done only by the `dot()` method of the array.

Broadcasting means the ability to perform operations between arrays of different sizes, like adding a number to a whole array. This works with operators on arrays as well.

Adding a number to an array is only a tiny example of the broadcasting ability. You can read more about it in [Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)
It's a very cool feature which saves memory and coding, but not so easy to understand at first reading.